# How to compress huge video files?

Tags: software-recommendation, compression, encoding, video-conversion

My Canon camera realize videos with the characteristics described in the picture.

[image]

The problem is that those files are huge (1Gb for 2 minutes).
Is there any application which allow me to compress or resize the films already made?

Comment: There are several applications, but you'll need to re-encode the videos.

Comment: 1Gb for 2 minutes of raw video is considered large since when?! I call that normal....   and I would assume this is asked before ;) have a look at "avidemux" and "avconv" or "ffmpeg"